# Compress archives with a flat structure using Winrar

Tags: c#, process, .net-4.0, winrar

I have a bunch of archives inside differents folders, I want to compact all the files to a .zip:

### What I'm trying:

```
(path)\WinRAR.exe a -afzip "(path)File.zip" "(path)ToCompress"
```

### What is wrong:

The Zip contain all the folders `(path)` not just the file `ToCompress`

---

### Edit:

Something similar as the `DotNetZip` parameter:

```
  -flat             - store the files in a flat dir structure; do not use the
                      directory paths from the source files.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-ep`.

From the Rar.exe help:

```
ep            Exclude paths from names
ep1           Exclude base directory from names
ep2           Expand paths to full
ep3           Expand paths to full including the drive letter
```